# Using Scopes to Separate Code

Tags: c#

I am trying to separate multiple parts of a function using Scopes but it doesn't see to work as shown in the following code

```
private static void Method()
{
    {
        //Code execution stops here. Although the return is defined inside a scope.
        return;
    }

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Whowaaah");
    }
}
```

So what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block (i.e. a sequence of statements within curly braces) affects the visibility of variables defined within it, not program flow. What you are seeing is completely normal behavior.

Perhaps you are looking for separate methods?

Comment: Any way to achieve what i want ?

Comment: I don't want to create tons of senseless separate methods though

Comment: @RuneS That depends on what you want. It isn't clear from your question what this is.

Comment: sorry for that but i can't recreate the situation in a virtual code, But the idea is that i do some different checks inside 1 timer for multiple things that affects my application

Comment: @RuneS, creating many -- and I'll say "smaller" -- methods would be in keeping with the Single Responsibility Principle and considered good programming practice.

Comment: on the other hand those checks can't be separated in alooot of methods because it will be very senseless

Comment: @RuneS This "senseless" measure of quality doesn't make a lot of sense. It would be difficult to suggest how to decompose your method into separate methods without seeing more code. In general though, if you name your methods consistently and clearly, and each method performs a single task or retrieves/calculates a single value, this should lead to a *decrease* in "senselessness".

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to have many methods even if they contain only a line of code.  This will be easier to maintain, especially since it sounds like you want to have one method that controls many other methods.

Two possible solutions for what you are doing could be this:

If you need to do multiple things:

```
private static void Method()
{
    if(ShouldDoSenseless1())
    {
        Senseless1();
    }

    if(ShouldDoSenseless2())
    {
        Senseless2();
    }

    if(ShouldDoSenseless3())
    {
        Senseless3();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Or, if you should only do a single thing among a list of choices:

```
private static void Method1()
{
    var doWhatNow = WhatStepShouldBePerformed();

    switch(doWhatNow)
    {
        case 1:
            DoSenseless1:
            break;
        case 2:
            DoSenseless1:
            break;
        case 3:
            DoSenseless1:
            break;
         break;
         // etc.
    }
}
```